# what is the behavior of related Keywords while publishing?

Tags: 2011, publishing, taxonomy

When I publish a Category, what is the impact on related Keywords of the Keywords in that Category? Will the related Keywords also be published?

Comment: Yes, the related keywords will also be published.

Comment: I agree with Kunal, but not because they're related, but simply because related keywords in the same Category are in the same Category. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you publish a category, all keywords *within* that category are published. Related keywords that belong to a *different* category are not published.

Comment: *If keywords were publishable* (they're not) I'd bet it'd work the other way--that keywords that relate/use the published item would get resolved or queued. ;-)

Comment: We are planning to use taxonomy for navigation. As per my understanding, related keywords can be used as "see also links" on website.Is there a way to publish related keywords when a Category is published(We are considering event system)? Also I would like to know if there are any other scenarios where I can use related keywords.